# A heat flow generalized problem featuring light bulb and oven

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-conduction

If an incandescent light bulb under constant power is taken from room temperature 25 deg C to an oven at 75 deg C, does the filament temperature increase by 50 C? Assume radiated power is negligible or constant. Assume steady state in both scenarios; power input is, to reiterate, equal in both scenarios.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by constant power. Does that mean you adjust the applied voltage to the bulb as necessary in order that $I^{2}R$ is constant?

Comment: Yes correct. Constant power

Comment: Yes, it will increase by 50C (numerical model)

Comment: If radiative power is constant, filament temperature must be constant. Or, rather (T^4-T0^4) must be constant. If radiative power is negligible, input power is negligible as well as filament temperature follows oven temperature.

Comment: OK I'm thinking of filament at a few hundred degrees C for that very small radiated power, and with that, a change of 50C should almost qualify the conditions stated. Esp considering the filament surface area is pretty miniscule

Answer (score 0):

As long as power is held constant, it should rise by 50 C. Generally it is assumed that temperatures on components and materials will rise or fall roughly in proportion to the rise or fall of ambient temperature, within applicable temperature ranges. Notable exceptions are when temperature regulation is involved (e.g. use of temperature regulating controls such as thermostats), or devices that self regulate temperature (e.g., PTC thermistors).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

OK what got this question started is climate change if you can believe that.

Proposed answer: a light bulb with constant power is at steady state at room temperature 25C. The filament is at a temperature below normal operation with slight glow. The steady state equations for this are Pin = Qdot + Pr where Qdot is heat flow to the ambient, Pin is power in and Pr is radiated power. Also T1 is filament temperature and T2 is ambient temperature. Parameter C is the thermal conductance between the filament and ambient. So the equation to my way of thinking should be Pin = (T1 - T2)C + Pr = k.

Now the bulb is moved to an oven at 75C and reaches steady state. With Pr miniscule and changing immeasurably, would it not be true that filament temperature steady state when the bulb is moved from the room to the oven, would increase by the same amount, i.e ΔT1 = ΔT2 = 75C - 25C? If the above eqn is constant, then a T2 increase should require a T1 increase.

So if this is correct, then global warming should include an increase in T of the entire planetary mass, including the mantle and core.

Comment: The system can get very far from equilibrium during the process though. The surface will reach almost the new temperature fairly quickly and then the filament will take much longer, because the heat flow is quite slow there. And that's even more so the case of Earth.